# SQL server inserting values from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a column of data from one table to another. The table I am trying to insert into is called MU.PROVIDERS. The table I am inserting from is called Sheet1$. (Imported from an excel sheet). The columns they have in common is called "NPI", a key that is common for all providers, so I am trying to insert based on this key. Not every NPI value in the Sheet1$ will put a corresponding RELAY_ID value into the 'MU.PROVIDERS' table. (There are more NPI's in the 'MU.PROVIDERS' than in Sheet1$) My query is as follows:

```
  INSERT INTO [MU.PROVIDERS] (RELAY_ID) 
  SELECT h.RELAY_ID
FROM  Sheet1$ as h  JOIN
 [MU.PROVIDERS]  as i ON h.NPI = i.NPI;
```

I am getting the error: 
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NPI', table 'MU.PROVIDERS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I do have the NPI column set as the primary key on the 'MU.PROVIDERS' table, but I am not inserting anything into this column so I do not understand the problem.

Comment: You are using an `Insert` statement. This will insert a new record. If you only specify a single field in the `insert`, the remaining fields in the table will automatically be set to `NULL` for that new record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an `update`.  `Insert` adds new rows.  `Update` changes the values of columns:

```
UPDATE i
    SET relay_id = h.relay_id
    FROM mu.Providers i JOIN
         Sheet1$ h
         ON h.NPI = i.NPI;
```

Comment: Yes, this worked thanks. I knew it was something simple, running the query worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may have defined the NPI column as the primary key.
But the primary key needs a unique value to identify a row.
If you don't provide the value with your INSERT statement you should define the NPI column as IDENTITY(1,1) to automagically create a new identity value.